# Drawing large images onto the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using the following code to draw images onto the canvas

```
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

This code works fine, but when I use images of large dimensions (around 1300 X 700) then the canvas is totally blank.

For reference I am also giving the code I am using to get the image

```
var image = new Image();
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

var img = "http://www.bigrhinos.com/ceabackend/index.php/drawingcontroller/getimage?level=1";

image.src = img;
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw after the image is loaded.

```
   var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    image.src='http://www.bigrhinos.com/ceabackend/index.php/drawingcontroller/getimage?level=1';
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
```